# How do I use a double integral to calculate the volume encased between two surfaces?

Tags: multiple-integral

In order to calculate the area within two curves f(x) and g(x), I can use a single integral, and my bounds will be the points of intersection where f(x) = g(x).

[image]
Given that f(x) is the red function and g(x) is the blue function, g(x) > f(x) over the region of integration. The points of intersection occur at $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$ Thus, the following integral will yield the enclosed area. $\int_{x_1}^{x_2} (g(x)-f(x)) dx$

How can I extend this process to double integrals? Say I wish to find the enclosed volume between two surfaces f(x,y) and g(x,y). 
[image]
Given f(x,y) is the blue function and g(x,y) is the purple function, g(x,y) > f(X,y) over the region of integration. The points of intersection occur over a set of points $(x_k,y_k,z_k)$ that lie along a curve. Thus, the double integral that will yield the enclosed volume is $\iint_D (g(x,y)-f(x,y)) dxdy$.

What the bounds for my region D?

Answer (score 1):

**Area between two functions**

Given the set:

$$
D := \left\{ (x,\,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : y \ge x^2, \; y \le 1-x^2 \right\},
$$

the *measure* of $D$ is equal to:

$$
||D|| 
:= \iint\limits_D 1\,\text{d}x\,\text{d}y 
= \int\limits_{x^2 \le 1-x^2} \text{d}x \int_{x^2}^{1-x^2} \text{d}y
= \int_{-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}}^{\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}} \left(1-2\,x^2\right)\text{d}x
= \frac{2\sqrt{2}}{3}\,.
$$

---

**Volume between two functions**

Given the set:

$$
\Omega := \left\{ (x,\,y,\,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 : z \ge x^2+y^2, \; z \le 1-x^2-y^2 \right\},
$$

the *measure* of $\Omega$ is equal to:

$$
||\Omega|| 
:= \iint\limits_{\Omega} 1\,\text{d}x\,\text{d}y\,\text{d}z 
= \iint\limits_{x^2+y^2 \le 1-x^2-y^2} \text{d}x\,\text{d}y \int_{x^2+y^2}^{1-x^2-y^2} \text{d}z
$$

i.e.

$$
||\Omega|| 
= \iint\limits_{x^2+y^2\le\left(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\right)^2} \left(1-2\,x^2-2\,y^2\right) \text{d}x\,\text{d}y
= \int_0^{2\pi} \text{d}\theta \int_0^{\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}} \left(1-2\,\rho^2\right)\rho\,\text{d}\rho 
= \frac{\pi}{4}\,.
$$

Answer (score 0):

Since you are working with the surfaces specified as $z=f(x,y), \, z=g(x,y)$, then your integration will be for $(x,y)$ varying over the region defined by $(x_k , y_k, 0)$.